# Selenium doesn't run next test operation?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, junit, selenium-chromedriver

I have my Selenium project set to run multiple test but it doesn't going into the next test procedure.

My code looks like this:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterSuite;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeSuite;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

@BeforeSuite
public static void chromeStart(){
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/home/taylor/projects/localtest/browsers/chromedriver");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.navigate().to("my site");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
}

@test 
public static void testLogin(){
    webdriver elements
}

@test
public static void anotherTest(){
   another test
}

@AfterSuite
public static void chromeClose(){
   driver.quit();
}
```

Comment: It just doesn't enter into the first test or in the second or both?

Comment: It runs the first one, but doesn't go into the second test

Comment: how are you trying to running it?

Comment: When i run it I run the whole thing

Comment: @TaylorGagne Can you put the code that you use in both tests please? Maybe the problem it's inside the test.

Comment: @Test

    public void testLogin() {


        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#showRightPush")).click();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("taylor");
        driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("taylor");
        driver.findElement(By.id("login-button")).click();


        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

Comment: @Test
    public void testCheckIn(){


        driver.findElement(By.id("checkin")).click();

        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#widget-icon > div > img")).click();

        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

Comment: When I run it with firefox it works correctly

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code there so it can be properly formatted.

Comment: How are you triggering the tests? What does your XML file look like? That's most likely where the problem is.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>worktester</groupId>
    <artifactId>worktester</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

Comment: <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
            <version>2.46.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


</project>

Answer (score -1):

I wonder how you are not even getting error if you are using @test.
Please try changing it to @Test and share your results (with code in detail)

e.g

```
@Test
    public void scenario2() {
        System.out.println("testClass3: scenario2");
    }


    @Test
    public void scenario12() {
        System.out.println("testClass3: scenario2");
    }
```

Comment: Questioner, Please provide justification when the answer is not useful to you.